# Are MySQL table names case sensitive?

Tags: mysql, debugging

Are MySQL table names case sensitive? Because I have a table named "eventai" in lower case, and as my Debug file says: `[23:50:29] CMySQLHandler::Query(DELETE FROM Eventai) - An error has occured. (Error ID: 1146, Table 'airidas?36_....Eventai' doesn't exist)` It can't find the table named "Eventai".

Connection information from Debug file:

```
[23:50:29]  
[23:50:29] ---------------------------
[23:50:29] MySQL Debugging activated (05/13/13)
[23:50:29] ---------------------------
[23:50:29]  
[23:50:29] >> mysql_connect( )
[23:50:29] CMySQLHandler::CMySQLHandler() - constructor called.
[23:50:29] CMySQLHandler::CMySQLHandler() - Connecting to "77.241.197.235" | DB: "airidas?36_..." | Username: "airidas_36" ...
[23:50:29] CMySQLHandler::Connect() - Connection was successful.
[23:50:29] CMySQLHandler::Connect() - Auto-Reconnect has been enabled.
[23:50:29] >> mysql_ping( Connection handle: 1 )
[23:50:29] CMySQLHandler::Ping() - Connection is still alive.
```

EDIT: Works now, don't respond

Comment: Depends on the operating system. Case sensitive for most varieties of Unix, not for Windows. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html (MySQL v5.0)

Comment: It's Debian 5 (Squeeze)

Answer (score 1):

> In MySQL, databases correspond to directories within the data directory. Each table within a database corresponds to at least one file within the database directory (and possibly more, depending on the storage engine). Consequently, the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of database and table names. **This means database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix.**
>
> Although database and table names are not case sensitive on some platforms, you should not refer to a given database or table using different cases within the same statement. The following statement would not work because it refers to a table both as `my_table` and as `MY_TABLE`:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MY_TABLE.col=1;
> ```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)